# Test Class Not Covered When Bulk data is passed

Tags: unit-test

Here is My Controller...

```
Public Class ObjectRelation {  
    Public List<Product2> pro{get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> AccountOptions {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> OpportunityOptions{get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> ProductOptions{get;set;}
    Public String AccName{get;set;}
    Public String OppName{get;set;}
    Public String prodName{get;set;}
    Public ObjectRelation()
    {   
        AccountOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        AccountOptions.add(new SelectOption('none','----Select Account----'));
        for (Account record : [select Id, Name from Account])
        {
          AccountOptions.add(new SelectOption(record.Id,record.Name));
        }                     
    } 
     Public List<SelectOption> getOpp(){
               OpportunityOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
               OpportunityOptions.add(new SelectOption('none','----Select Opportunity----'));
              for (Opportunity record : [select id,name from Opportunity where Account.Id =: AccName] )
                {
                      OpportunityOptions.add(new SelectOption(record.Id,record.Name));
                }  
                System.Debug('####'+OpportunityOptions);
                return OpportunityOptions;
     }
     Public List<SelectOption> getProd(){
        ProductOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        ProductOptions.add(new SelectOption('none','----Select Product----'));
        for (OpportunityLineItem record : [SELECT Id,PricebookEntry.Product2Id,PricebookEntry.Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId =: OppName] )
        {
              ProductOptions.add(new SelectOption(record.PricebookEntry.Product2Id,record.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name));
        }  
        return ProductOptions;
     }
     Public List<Product2> GetDisplayProduct(){
          pro = new List<Product2>();
          pro = [Select id,Name,ProductCode,Description,IsActive from Product2 where id =: prodName ];
          if(OppName == '0069000000DY2nV'){
          System.debug('@'+prodName);
        }
        else{
            System.debug('@@'+prodName);
        }
          string sString = 'some*Stuff*vivek';
        return pro;       
     }
     public PageReference Save(){         
         try{
                if(pro.size() > 0){
                  upsert pro;    
                  ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Record Successfully Updated'));   
                }
            } catch (DMLException e){
                // show the messages to the user
                ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            }             
         return null;
     }
}
```

TestClass of Above Controller...to test 200 records...

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
Public class TestObjectRelation {
    Static TestMethod void TestObjectRelation (){
        ObjectRelation objMain = new ObjectRelation();
        List<Account> lstacc = new List<Account>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<200;i++){
            Account acc = new Account(name='vivek113'+i);
            lstacc.add(acc);
            objMain.AccName = lstacc[i].Id;
        }    
        System.debug('****accid'+objMain.AccName);   
        insert lstacc; 
        List<Opportunity> lstopp = new List<Opportunity>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<200;i++){
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(AccountId=lstacc[i].id,name='opp'+i,StageName='abc'+i,CloseDate=System.today()+i,optname__c='opp'+i);
            lstopp.add(opp);
            objMain.oppName = lstopp[i].Id;
        } 
        insert lstopp;   
        List<Product2> lstprod = new List<Product2>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<200;i++){
            Product2 prod = new Product2(name='new'+i,IsActive = true);
            lstprod.add(prod);
            objMain.prodName = lstprod[i].Id;
        }
        insert lstprod;       
        List<Pricebook2> lstpricebook2 = new List<Pricebook2>();        
             Pricebook2 objprice = [select Id from PriceBook2 where IsStandard=True];
             objprice.IsActive = true;
             lstpricebook2.add(objprice);

        update lstpricebook2;        
        List<PricebookEntry> lstpricebookentry = new  List<PricebookEntry>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<200;i++){
            PricebookEntry standardPrice= new PricebookEntry (Product2Id = lstprod[i].id,unitprice=20+i,Pricebook2Id = objprice.id,UseStandardPrice=false,isActive=true);
            lstpricebookentry.add(standardPrice);           
        }
        insert lstpricebookentry;        
        List<OpportunityLineItem> lstopplineitem = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<200;i++){
           OpportunityLineItem objoppline = new OpportunityLineItem (OpportunityId=lstopp[i].id,pricebookentryId=lstpricebookentry[i].id,Quantity=10,totalprice=40);
           lstopplineitem.add(objoppline);        
        }
        insert lstopplineitem;         
        objMain.getopp();
        objMain.getprod(); 
        objMain.getdisplayProduct();
        objMain.save();
    }
}
```

This Test Class is fully worked for Single Record...But here i test 200 of data in loop here is snapshot of not covered part....so what can i do please Help me......

[image]

Comment: That is also my post sir...!!!

Comment: I know that, it is quite easy to check :)
Problem is that you duplicated post, and as I belive we don't want to do this on this forum

Comment: sorry sir for that...next time i keep in mind..

Answer (score 0):

Your query

```
Select id,name from Opportunity where Account.Id =: AccName
```

Is not returning any results. I believe this is because you are trying to set AccName on your ObjectRelation class **before** you have inserted the list of accounts in this block here:

```
ObjectRelation objMain = new ObjectRelation();
    List<Account> lstacc = new List<Account>();
    for(Integer i=0;i<200;i++){
        Account acc = new Account(name='vivek113'+i);
        lstacc.add(acc);
        objMain.AccName = lstacc[i].Id;
    }    
    System.debug('****accid'+objMain.AccName);   
    insert lstacc;
```

Setting

Won't have an ID value until 
    insert lstacc;

has been called.

I think the best course of action is to create the list 1stacc, and insert it, and then iterate though the list again to call your 
    objMain.AccName = lstacc[i].Id;

That said, I'm not sure why you are setting AccName over and over again anyway?

Comment: Sir AccName is a string variable to store the id...and it is used in the VF page..selectlist...value..part...ex{!AccName}

Comment: Ok, but lstacc[i].Id **has no value** where it is used in your for loop. The Id is not set on a record until it is inserted. (and this is true in each of your loops) So AccName, oppName, and prodName are all empty in ObjectRelation when you call your methods at the bottom.

Comment: Thank u sir i got the solution as per your instruction....thanks again....

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. please select the answer as correct then to keep the StackExchange statistics accurate :)